# Finding specific data in SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I hope someone can help me with this, I am new in SQL and this makes me confuse.
I want to find a specific/matched data in mySQL table via inputbox, This code only find data in the first row and doesn't recognize the second and the rest data in the row of my database..

here is my code..

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
myConn
Dim holdstr As String
holdstr = InputBox("Enter Number")
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM lemployees ", conn
Do Until rs.EOF

If holdstr = "" Then
conn.Close
Exit Sub
End If

If holdstr = rs!ENumber Then
MsgBox "Record found!", vbInformation, "Message"

UserForm2.lblnum.Caption = rs!ENumber
UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = rs!ELName
UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = rs!EFName
UserForm2.TextBox4.Text = rs!EMName
UserForm2.boxPos = rs!EDepartment
UserForm2.TextBox6.Text = rs!EAge
UserForm2.TextBox7.Text = rs!EHourlyPaid
UserForm2.TextBox8.Text = rs!ECitizen

conn.Close
Exit Sub
Else
MsgBox "Record not found", vbInformation, "Message"
Exit Sub
End If
Loop
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have given an answer as to why you only see the first row.  However, you should set up your querries so that it only returns the correct row.

Comment: @Taemyr ..It worked! thanks.. Answer really appreaciated :D

Comment: Good:) Nice if you Could upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exit the Sub inside the loop.  Even if the item you are looking for is not found.

Try

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
myConn
Dim holdstr As String
holdstr = InputBox("Enter Number")

If holdstr = "" Then
  Exit Sub
End If

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM lemployees ", conn
Do Until rs.EOF
  If holdstr = rs!ENumber Then
    MsgBox "Record found!", vbInformation, "Message"

    UserForm2.lblnum.Caption = rs!ENumber
    UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = rs!ELName
    UserForm2.TextBox3.Text = rs!EFName
    UserForm2.TextBox4.Text = rs!EMName
    UserForm2.boxPos = rs!EDepartment
    UserForm2.TextBox6.Text = rs!EAge
    UserForm2.TextBox7.Text = rs!EHourlyPaid
    UserForm2.TextBox8.Text = rs!ECitizen

    conn.Close
    Exit Sub
    End If
  Loop
MsgBox "Record not found", vbInformation, "Message"
conn.Close
Exit Sub
```